# stat_cor for a different variable than the one plotted

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have this plot:

```
mtcars$mpg_level <- as.character(as.integer(mtcars$mpg))
p1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg_level, color=mpg_level , shape=mpg_level)) + geom_point()
p1 <- p1 + scale_shape_manual(values = 1:length(unique(mtcars$mpg_level)))
```

[image]

I want to have a label for the correlation between `mpg` and `disp`

This does not work:

```
p2 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg_level, color=mpg_level , shape=mpg_level)) + geom_point()
p2 <- p2 + stat_cor(aes(label = ..rr.label..), color = "red", geom = "label", digits = 2, size = 3)
p2 <- p2 + scale_shape_manual(values = 1:length(unique(mtcars$mpg_level)))
```

gives:

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_cor()`
Caused by error in `cor.test.default()`:
! not enough finite observations
```

so I suspect it tries to get the correlation between each level of `mpg_level`, which is supported by this working:

```
p3 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
p3 <- p3 + stat_cor(aes(label = ..rr.label..), color = "red", geom = "label", digits = 2, size = 3)
```

[image]

I feel like it needs to be something like this, where I add `mpg` and `disp` separately to `stat_cor`, but obviously does not work:

```
p4 <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg_level, color=mpg_level , shape=mpg_level)) + geom_point()
p4 <- p4 + stat_cor(aes(x=disp, y=mpg, label = ..rr.label..), color = "red", geom = "label", digits = 2, size = 3)
p4 <- p4 + scale_shape_manual(values = 1:length(unique(mtcars$mpg_level)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th issue is that your data is grouped by `mpg_level`. To get your desired correlation via `stat_cor` you have to additionally set the `group` aes to override the default grouping, i.e. add `group=1`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

mtcars$mpg_level <- as.character(as.integer(mtcars$mpg))

p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg_level, color = mpg_level, shape = mpg_level)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = seq_along(unique(mtcars$mpg_level))) 

p +
  ggpubr::stat_cor(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, label = after_stat(rr.label), group = 1),
    color = "red", geom = "label", digits = 2, size = 3,
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  )
```

[image]

However, while this works and gives the desired correlation the label is placed at the max value of `mpg` not the max `mpg_level`. To fix that you have to explicitly set the label position.

Note: Of course could this be avoided by mapping `mpg` on `y` for the points too.

```r
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg_level, color = mpg_level, shape = mpg_level)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = seq_along(unique(mtcars$mpg_level))) 

p +
  ggpubr::stat_cor(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, label = after_stat(rr.label), group = 1),
    color = "red", geom = "label", digits = 2, size = 3,
    inherit.aes = FALSE, label.y = "34"
  )
```

[image]